# How do I create an alert which fires when one of many machines fails to report a heartbeat?

Tags: azure, logging, kql, azure-alerts

Overall I'm trying to set up an azure alert to email me when a computer goes down by using the Heartbeat table.

Let's say I have 5 machines in my Azure subscription, and they each report once per minute to the table called Heartbeat, so it looks something like this:

[image: Table Example]

Currently, I can query "Heartbeat | where Computer == 'computer-name'| where TimeGenerated > ago(5m)" and figure out when one computer has not been reporting in the last 5 minutes, and is down ([thank you to this great article for that query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/vm/tutorial-monitor-vm-alert)).

I am not very experienced with any query language, so I am wondering if it is possible to have 1 query which can check to see if there was ANY computer which stopped sending it's logs over the last 5-10 minute period, and thus would be down. Azure uses KQL, or Kusto Query Language for it's queries and there is documentation in the link above.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

one option is to calculate the max report time for each computer, then filter to the ones whose max report time is older than 5 minutes ago:

```
let all_computers_lookback = 12h
;
let monitor_looback = 5m
;
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > ago(all_computers_lookback)
| summarize last_reported = max(TimeGenerated) by computer
| where last_reported < ago(monitor_looback)
```

another alternative:

- the first part creates an "inventory" of all computers that reported at least once in the last  (e.g. 12 hours).
- the second part finds all computers that reported at least once in the last  (e.g. 5 minutes)
- the third and final part finds the difference between the two (i.e. all computers that didn't report in the last 5 minutes)

*Note: if you have more than 1M computers, you can use the `join` operator instead of the `in()` operator*

```
let all_computers_lookback = 12h
;
let monitor_looback = 5m
;
let all_computers = 
    Heartbeat
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(all_computers_lookback)
    | distinct computer
;
let reporting_computers = 
    Heartbeat
    | where TimeGenerated > ago(monitor_looback)
    | distinct computer
;
let non_reporting_computers =
    all_computers
    | where computer !in(reporting_computers)
;
non_reporting_computers
```